# Should I be wiping or removing contact cleaner?

Tags: electrical, cleaning

After testing a part (solenoid, sensor, etc) in an older vehicle, I have gotten in the habit of blasting the connection socket and plug with contact cleaner.

It's basically impossible to wipe the contact cleaner off in these locations, so I just re-plug the socket and move on.

Is this the right way to use an automotive contact cleaner, or do I need to wipe, rinse, or otherwise remove the cleaner after it's applied?

The cleaner itself has zero instructions on the bottle.

Comment: Is it an organic solvent like mek or lacquer thinner ,no problem. If it is like a copper cleaner , don't use it.

Comment: It specifically says automotive contact cleaner, not for use on household electronics, but there's no hint about the formula. I probably should have bought something with better labelling.

Comment: I did some more digging on the product I'm using and it's basically pure heptane with some proprietary degreasers, supposed to evaporate fully away, so it sounds like I'm using it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used CRC electrical cleaner for automotive use in the same manner you describe, on an old car, for years.  It has never done any damage.  I think the stuff evaporates without causing harm.